# Using find to process folder names (containing whitespace and ') for a bash script fails

Tags: bash, shell, find, escaping, whitespace

Using bash version 5.*

I created a script that creates a script that will play video and/or audio files in the given folder, the created playing-multimedia-files script using this function

```
ffprobe -hide_banner 2>&1 "$*" |grep Stream|grep "Video:" >/dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    # return zero -> video file: default
    ffplay -autoexit -hide_banner -fs -i "$*"
else
    # return non-zero -> audio only - adjusting…
    ffplay -autoexit -hide_banner -showmode waves -x 500 -y 150 -i "$*"
fi
}
```

The script creating these scripts is called **make-ffplay-script** and has no issue when a given folder name has "/" at its end, **but has issues when the given folder name has "./" at the beginning** of the given folder name; it is meant for relative paths only, so that the folder "foldername/" containing the video and/or audio files can moved anywhere and the corresponding foldername.sh can be moved / copied alongside the folder and executing ./foldername.sh will play the files in "foldername/" regardless were "foldername/" and  foldername.sh are - as long as "foldername/" and "foldername.sh" sit in the same folder.

All well so far, as long as I call my script make-ffplay-script manually for each folder. When escaped with either 'single' or "double" quotes or \ when the folder name contains whitespace, my script make-ffplay-script handles the folder names correctly. When a folder name contains ' (single quote character) I use escaping via "" or \ ; These kind of folder names also work. **Folder/Filenames containing " (double quote character) do not exist, nor do folder names containing new line characters or the Null byte character.**

Now my issue, I would like to use "find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1" for the list of folders in the current directory (no sub-folders) and feed that somehow to my make-ffplay-script thus creating scripts for all folders; tried several approaches for escaping the whitespaces (or the ' ) but all fail.

I created dummy folders with dummy.mp3 files in these to test if all works as it should:

```
r@rava:/tmp/test$ mkdir "testdir" "testdir with space" "testdir's space"
r@rava:/tmp/test$ touch "testdir/dummy.mp3" "testdir with space/dummy.mp3" "testdir's space/dummy.mp3"
r@rava:/tmp/test$ find .
.
./testdir's space
./testdir's space/dummy.mp3
./testdir with space
./testdir with space/dummy.mp3
./testdir
./testdir/dummy.mp3
```

When using "find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1" by itself find's result works as intended:

```
r@rava:/tmp/test$ find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 
./testdir's space
./testdir with space
./testdir
```

Then I try using a solution adopted from an answer on here and it fails:

```
r@rava:/tmp/test$ for d in $(find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1); do echo make-ffplay-script $d >> myfindloop.sh; done
r@rava:/tmp/test$ cat myfindloop.sh 
make-ffplay-script ./testdir's
make-ffplay-script space
make-ffplay-script ./testdir
make-ffplay-script with
make-ffplay-script space
make-ffplay-script ./testdir

r@rava:/tmp/test$ rm myfindloop.sh 

r@rava:/tmp/test$ for d in $(find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1); do echo make-ffplay-script \""$d"\" >> myfindloop.sh; done
r@rava:/tmp/test$ cat myfindloop.sh 
make-ffplay-script "./testdir's"
make-ffplay-script "space"
make-ffplay-script "./testdir"
make-ffplay-script "with"
make-ffplay-script "space"
make-ffplay-script "./testdir"

r@rava:/tmp/test$ rm myfindloop.sh 

r@rava:/tmp/test$ for d in $(find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1); do echo make-ffplay-script "$d" >> myfindloop.sh; done
r@rava:/tmp/test$ cat myfindloop.sh 
make-ffplay-script ./testdir's
make-ffplay-script space
make-ffplay-script ./testdir
make-ffplay-script with
make-ffplay-script space
make-ffplay-script ./testdir
```

Why is using unquoted $d and quoted "$q" result in the same error?

What must be done so that my resulting myfindloop.sh looks like this:

```
make-ffplay-script "testdir's space"
make-ffplay-script "testdir with space"
make-ffplay-script "testdir"
```

**Update**
Thanks to @pjh this code:

```
for d in */ ; do echo make-ffplay-script \""$d"\"; done > myfindloop.sh
```

does the trick. I added the extra " because these are needed or else myfindloop.sh would fail when it comes to any folder containing whitespace.
You find these answers below in the comments area hidden by default ("Show ? more comments").

I personally prefer pjh's printf approach.

One last info: regardless if ones uses the *echo with added "* or the *printf approach*, after the creation of myfindloop.sh this is needed

```
chmod a+x myfindloop.sh
```

to make the resulting script executable.

Comment: if you just want immediate subdirectories of the current directory why not just use `for d in */` ? and if the trailing slash is a problem you can refer to `"${d%/}"` instead of `"$d"`. If you need dot paths you can set `dotglob` option

Comment: could also be worth setting `nullglob` so getting `*/` as value of `d` is not ambiguous

Comment: `$(find ...)` returns a string. the shell splits that string into "words" and then assigns them one at a time to `d`. that's why quoting `$d` later doesn't make any difference

Comment: IMHO, way too much info here. Please read about [mcve] and read the section [How to turn a bad script into a good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info). (this advice applies to all languages, not just bash).  Also https://shellcheck.net is the first place to figure out syntax problems. Be sure to include #!/bin/bash (or other) as your first line of scripting. Good luck.

Comment: `for d in $(find ...)` is fundamentally broken.  See [Bash Pitfalls #1 (for f in $(ls ...))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).  Unfortunately, it's very common to see such code in questions and answers on Stack Overflow (even in accepted and much-upvoted answers).  There are *very* few sources of good shell code.  [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) is an excellent tool for identifying common errors (including this one) in shell code.

Comment: @pjh thanks for that, as I wrote and as you confirmed: I used an answer I found here as a base of my attempt. That article I took the idea from had not a single comment about how broken _for f in [find]_ (not _for f in $(ls …))_ is.)

Comment: **@jhnc** I will try _for d in */_ and _"${d%/}"_ and _setting nullglob_. Thanks for all these infos.

Comment: **@jhnc**  `for d in */ ; do echo make-ffplay-script "$d" > myfindloop.sh; done` only results in `make-ffplay-script testdir/` - both folders with whitespace are not processed. Changing `shopt -s nullglob` not changes anything, still the only thing in myfindloop.sh is `make-ffplay-script testdir/` . Using `ls -d */` gives me all three existing folders: `testdir\ with\ space/  testdir's\ space/  testdir/` but I want to avoid using ls. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Rava, `for d in */ ; do echo make-ffplay-script "$d" > myfindloop.sh; done` doesn't do what you want because the `myfindloop.sh` file is completely overwritten each time round the loop.  Try `for d in */ ; do echo make-ffplay-script "$d"; done > myfindloop.sh` instead.

Comment: @Rava, regarding the lack of comments on broken code that uses `for f in $(find ...)`, that is not unusual.  Most shell users, including some who have been using it for decades, are not aware of the common pitfalls.  Some who are aware of them are happy to use, or post as answers, broken code that happens to work for a restricted set of files.  Bad code is so pervasive that it is not possible for people who know and care about bad code to comment on all of it.  A practical way to reduce your exposure to bad code is to use Python instead of shell and the other legacy Unix tools.

Comment: Thanks @pjh this code: `for d in */ ; do echo make-ffplay-script \""$d"\"; done > myfindloop.sh` does the trick. Adding the extra " is needed or else myfindloop.sh would fail when it comes to any folder containing whitespace.

Comment: See also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020

Comment: @tripleee thanks for that, the BASH FAQ on  mywiki.wooledge.org is very helpful indeed, posted it on my Linux forum in the "Linux Basics" thread to share the love and knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

One way to generate an equivalent to your required `myfindloop.sh` file is:

```
for d in */ ; do printf 'make-ffplay-script %q\n' "${d%/}"; done > myfindloop.sh
```

- The `%q` format for `printf` produces output that is properly quoted for reading by the shell, but it usually doesn't use double quotes.  An example full output line is `make-ffplay-script testdir\ with\ space`.  That is exactly equivalent to `make-ffplay-script "testdir with space"` as a shell command.
- See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) for an explanation of `${d%/}`.

Comment: Thanks  that works as well as my edited original question where I manually put in literal " into what will be written in myfindloop.sh . Even when both versions work **I prefer yours** since `printf` is more capable when it comes to many things than a mere `echo` (string manipulation being just one of these).

Comment: I just overwrote the 3 dummy-files with dummy.mp3 symlinks in the 3 test folders symlinking to a test mp3 and created 6 scripts made by make-ffplay-script - two for each of the 3 folders, one using the _echo with added "_ and one using the _printf approach_ and _tested all 6 scripts, and all work as intended_. Thanks a lot @pjh

Comment: One last thing, both variants of myfindloop.sh must be made executable prior it all working, so `chmod  a+x myfindloop.sh` or `chmod -v a+x myfindloop.sh` is also needed after the myfindloop.sh file got created.